# Communicate between UpdatePanels ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, multiview

I have placed a treeView in One Update Panel and Each View in one update Panel
  something like this

```
 
   <UpdatePanel id="UP1">
     <ContentTemplate>
       <TreeView/>
     </ContentTemplate>
  </UpdatePanel>

   <MultiView>
    <UpdatePanel id="UP2">
      <View1/>
     </UpdatePanel>
```

Now I want to know how I can make sure When I click any node of TreeView respective Views should get displayed

Answer (score 2):

Another way of approaching it would be to call UP2.Update() from the codebehind if you have code for the click event of the Treeview. Remember, UP2 needs to have its RenderMode set to Conditional for this to work. Hope it helps

Comment: This is the simplist and best answer to this issue.  I'd give the same advice  although setting the mode to conditional is not required for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Add an AsyncPostBackTrigger to the second updatePanel, so it gets updated when the TreeView Click event is fired.

```
<Asp:UpdatePanel id="UP2">
   <View1/>
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TreeView1" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
</Asp:UpdatePanel>
```

OK, Here Is a working Example.

The Markup:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTreeView" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" 
                            onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged">
                            <Nodes>
                                <asp:TreeNode Text="GrandFather" Value="GrandFather">
                                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Father" Value="Father">
                                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Son" Value="Son"></asp:TreeNode>
                                    </asp:TreeNode>
                                </asp:TreeNode>
                            </Nodes>
                        </asp:TreeView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upView" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TreeView1" 
                            EventName="SelectedNodeChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

The code behind:

```
    protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = TreeView1.SelectedValue;
    }
```